# Phonegap Hotshot book example apps doesn't working

Tags: android, cordova

Just bought PhoneGap 2.x Mobile Application Development Hotshot book to improve my knowledge working with PhoneGap and try to run some apps from the book. I downloaded whose apps from their github repository (https://github.com/photokandyStudios/PhoneGap-HotShot-Book-Code-Bundle) and, for example, tried to run first app from Chapter1 (QuizApp). Imported that whole folder with Eclipse(Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace) and when I try to run it on my emulator or on my real Android device, it just stops working and shuts down. Looks like everything is in their right places, but nothing.

Here I will provide my LogCat information:

```
07-26 15:24:51.418: E/Trace(853): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-26 15:24:51.688: W/dalvikvm(853): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/phonegaphotshot/QuizTime/QuizTime; (15)
07-26 15:24:51.688: W/dalvikvm(853): Link of class 'Lcom/phonegaphotshot/QuizTime/QuizTime;' failed
07-26 15:24:51.718: D/AndroidRuntime(853): Shutting down VM
07-26 15:24:51.718: W/dalvikvm(853): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime/com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime.QuizTime}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime.QuizTime
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime.QuizTime
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
07-26 15:24:51.798: E/AndroidRuntime(853):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! If someone having similar problem, just do this step by step:

Right click on Cordovaxxx.jar -> Configure Build Path in Tab Order and Export and make sure these ones are selected:

```
1. Android (in my case was Adnroid 4.1.2)
2. Android Dependencies
3. Cordova....
4. ..../src
5. ..../gen
```

Comment: Have you tried project 6? It crashes on my Android phone with out of memory errors...